# How to give a mob smooth custom motion in MCJE 1.16

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a boss battle, and I wanted the boss to walk smoothly in a certain direction. I have tried:

```
/summon zombie ~ ~1 ~ {CustomName:"Zombo",CustomNameVisible:1,Motion:[0.0,0.0,-12.0], Attributes:[{Name:generic.movementSpeed,Base:2}
```

but the zombie does not smoothly move, it actually teleports. I thought of having a bunch of command blocks all in a row that kill the zombie and summon a new one every block, giving it the appearance of smooth motion. However, I would like something that I can run in just a few command blocks. Does anyone have experience with things like this? Thanks!

Comment: Did you know that there is a secret mob that Mojang tried to hide called "Giant"? The "Giant" mob is zombie textured and takes a while to kill having 200 HP and packs a punch! Use this command to summon one in (there is no spawn egg for this mob): `/summon giant ~ ~1 ~ {CustomName:"Zombo",CustomNameVisible:1,Motion:[0.0,0.0,-12.0],Attributes:[{Name:generic.movementSpeed,Base:2}`

Comment: You'll probably need to teleport the mob multiple times, using scoreboards to keep track of its current state. There's no way in the base game to get a mob to move overtime

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will use that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little tidbit of information: if an entity that usually walks is teleported relatively every tick, it will play its walking animation to match the speed that it's teleporting.

as an example, let's summon a giant with no AI for funsies:

`summon giant ~ ~ ~ {NoAI:1b}`

then put this into a repeating command block:

`execute as @e[type=minecraft:giant] at @s run teleport @s ^ ^ ^.1`

It'll actually make the giant appear to walk.

What you can do if you would like it to track a certain path is place stairs (or any 4-directional block) under the ground and turn the giant accordingly. Example:

```
execute as @e[type=minecraft:giant] at @s if block ~ ~-2 ~ minecraft:oak_stairs[facing=east] run teleport @s ~ ~ ~ 270 0
execute as @e[type=minecraft:giant] at @s if block ~ ~-2 ~ minecraft:oak_stairs[facing=west] run teleport @s ~ ~ ~ 90 0
execute as @e[type=minecraft:giant] at @s if block ~ ~-2 ~ minecraft:oak_stairs[facing=south] run teleport @s ~ ~ ~ 0 0
execute as @e[type=minecraft:giant] at @s if block ~ ~-2 ~ minecraft:oak_stairs[facing=north] run teleport @s ~ ~ ~ 180 0
```

This will turn the giant to face whatever direction a stair 2 blocks under it is facing.
In conjunction with the other command, this will make the giant walk forward until it hits a stair, then change direction based on where the stair is pointing, and continue until it reaches the next one. I hope this was clear enough

Comment: Thanks! This helped a ton!

Comment: Good to hear! I forgot to mention that you should divide whatever you want the speed of the mob to be by 20, as that's the tick speed of a minecraft server. Teleporting it 0.1 block forward as shown in the example will make it go 2 blocks per second